# SQLCMD for SQL Server on Windows Authentication is not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-administration

Thanks for looking into my post. I am facing issue while connecting SQL Server on Linux using windows authentication account if I use local account then things are working fine without any issue. Please let me know what changes are required here.

***ERROR***

```
/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S aaa.com -U aaa -d master
Password:
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login failed for user 'aaa'..

/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S aaa.com -U 'test' -d master -P Hello1234
1> select @@servername
2> go
```

Comment: The -E switch does not require the -U parameter.  Including it will result in an error.

Comment: sqlcmd -S SERVERNAME,49399 -U User -P pwd -d DatabaseName -Q "select @@servername;"

Comment: @FrancescoMantovani I am getting following error Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : TCP Provider: Error code 0x2AF9.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online..

Comment: /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S aaa.com,1433 -U aaa -d master -Q "select @@servername"
Password:
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login failed for user 'aaa'..